# I am making a mp3 payer in Python3 (also using Tkinter) but I am facing a dead end

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am making a menu func which adds songs to the player.

```
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:\\Users\\Soham\\Music', title="Choose a 
    song!",filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"), ))
    song_name = song.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    song_list.insert(END, song_name)
```

Then afterwards I have a play button which is coded to play the song added -

```
play_button = Button(controls_frame, image=play_button_img,borderwidth=0, command = play)
play_button.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5)
```

So, the func, `play()`'s code is -

```
def play():
    song = song_list.get(ACTIVE)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
```

But here dong variable in play() is actually just the name of song as it is already split off in add_song().And pygame needs the entire path as the song is not in the same directory as the python file. So pygame cannot open and play the song resulting in the error -

```
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
       1885, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
       File "c:\Users\Soham\Desktop\HM MP.py", line 26, in play
  pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
  pygame.error: Couldn't open 'Avicii - The Nights'
```

So what can I do about this , is there another way where I can split off the path for displaying  the song name creating no problems for `pygame` to play the music??

Also, I am using Windows 10 Pro , high end machine and using Python 3.

Comment: You can make a dictionary with the keys being the song name and the values being the full path to the file.  Then use that dictionary to load from the full file path retrieved from the dictionary based on the song name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are inserting the song on to the list box and play it from there, what you could do is, make a dictionary of index starting from 0 as key and values as list of song name and path, so its something like like `song_dict = {idx:[song_name,song_path]}`. So each idx will be your selection from the listbox. I have made an example with this, take a look:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pygame

root = Tk()
pygame.mixer.init()

song_dict = {} # Empty dict to assign values to it
count = 0 # An idx number to it increase later
def add_song():
    global count
    
    song_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C://Users//Soham//Music', title="Choose a song!",filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"), ))
    song_name = song_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    song_dict[count] = [song_name,song_path] # Create the desired dictionary 
    song_list.insert(END, song_name) # Insert just the song_name to the Listbox

    count += 1 # Increase the idx number 

def play_song(*args):
    idx = song_list.curselection()[0] # Get the index of the selected item
    song = song_dict[idx][1] # Get the corresponding song from the dictionary 
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song) # Load the song
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0) # Play the song


song_list = Listbox(root,width=50)
song_list.pack(pady=10)

choose = Button(root,text='Choose song',command=add_song)
choose.pack(pady=10)

song_list.bind('<Double-Button-1>',play_song) # Just double click the desired song to play

root.mainloop()
```

Just double click the song you want to play. You can also use a button instead of `bind()` like you do in your code.

An example of how `song_dict` will structure like:

```
{0: ['Shawn Mendes - Perfectly Wrong', 'C:/PyProjects/sONGS/Shawn Mendes - Perfectly Wrong.mp3'],
1: ['Lil Nas X - Old Town Road (feat', 'C:/PyProjects/sONGS/Lil Nas X - Old Town Road (feat. Billy Ray Cyrus) - Remix.mp3'],
2: ['NF - Time - Edit', 'C:/PyProjects/sONGS/NF - Time - Edit.mp3']}
```

Though I would also recommend to make a button to ask for directory and take all the mp3 files in that directory and populate the listbox.

If you want to use `filedialog.askopenfilenames` then you can edit the function as below:

```
import os

def add_song():
    songs_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='C://Users//Soham//Music', title="Choose a song!")

    for count,song in enumerate(songs_path):
        song_name = os.path.basename(song)
        song_dict[count] = [song_name,song] # Create the desired dictionary 
        song_list.insert(END, song_name) # Insert just the song_name to the Listbox
```

In this case you don't need the pre defined `count` variable, as we make them from the `for` loop.

**EDIT:**
Instead of using `split`, why not just use `os.path`, so you can get the basename from the path, like:

```
import os

song_name = os.path.basename(song_path) # If its tuple then loop through and follow
```

Comment: Sure,np,also what if i have filenames instead of filename in song_path, because that would create a tuple , so then how would i split cause i am pretty sure there is nothing as split for tuples

Comment: Thanks man , you just helped me a ton :D Also , i actually like the idea of button for a directory

Comment: Hey u must think im a weirdo , but again when i hit the next song button it again gives me a error, any ideas to go around the obstackle. Sorry for asking SOO MANY QUESTIONS!

Comment: @CoderMan Whats the error? And a next song button wasnt mentioned in the question, maybe you should ask new question about it.

Comment: ok but can u just like u know post it here

Comment: @CoderMan 3 edits have already been made to the answer, more edits will just bulk it up and make it more clumsy. I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65519693/i-am-making-a-mp3-player-and-i-need-a-forward-button-to-it-but-cant-seem-to-fi

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `dict` having `{'song name': 'file path'}`

Comment: This answer was entered 5 minutes after I said this in a comment on the OP.

Comment: i did not see your comment, maybe i did not refresh before answering. nothing against you. as you can see from my profile, m a beginner in this. i took very long in adding the answer. moreover the answer was edited later. (that shows how bad the answer was written) @RufusVS